# Turning an array of integers into an array of nonnegative integers

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Start with an array of integers so that the sum of the values is some positive integer `S`. The following routine always terminates in the same number of steps with the same results. Why is this?

Start with an array `x = [x_0, x_1, ..., x_N-1]` such that all `x_i`'s are integers. While there is a negative entry, do the following:

- Choose any index `i` such that `x_i < 0`.
- Add `x_i` (a negative number) to `x_(i-1 % N)`.
- Add `x_i` (a negative number) to `x_(i+1 % N)`.
- Replace `x_i` with `-x_i` (a positive number).

This process maintains the property that `x_0 + x_1 + ... + x_N-1 = S`. For any given starting array `x`, no matter which index is chosen at any step, the number of times one goes through these steps is the same as is the resulting vector. It is not even obvious (to me, at least) that this process terminates in finite time, let alone has this nice invariant property.

EXAMPLE:

Take `x = [4 , -1, -2]` and flipping `x_1` to start, the result is

```
[4, -1, -2]
[3, 1, -3]
[0, -2, 3]
[-2, 2, 1]
[2, 0, -1]
[1, -1, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
```

On the other hand, flipping `x_2` to start gives

```
[4, -1, -2]
[2, -3, 2]
[-1, 3, -1]
[1, 2, -2]
[-1, 0, 2]
[1, -1, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
```

and the final way give this solution with arrays reversed from the third on down if you choose `x_2` instead of `x_0` to flip at the third array. In all cases, 6 steps lead to `[0,1,0]`.

I have an argument for why this is true, but it seems to me to be overly complicated (it has to do with [Coxeter groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group)). Does anyone have a more direct way to think about why this happens? Even finding a reason why this should terminate would be great.

Bonus points to anyone who finds a way to determine the number of steps for a given array (without going through the process).

Comment: Shouldn't the array be [x_0, x_1, ... x_N-1] for the modulo thing to work?

Comment: Start with `[3, -1, -1]`.  If I choose element 1, I get `[4, 1, 0]`. If instead I choose element 2, I get `[4, 0, 1]`.  So "...as is the resulting vector" appears to be an overstatement...

Comment: @Nemo: flipping x_1 gives `[2,1,-2]` and flipping x_2 gives `[2,-2,1]`, so either way the process has not yet ended.

Comment: Also, start with [4, -2, -1].  If I choose element 1, I get [6, 0, 1] and terminate in one iteration.  If instead I choose element 2, I get [5, -1, 1] and I have to go through another iteration.  Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Got it; I was using the new x_i instead of the original x_i.

Comment: @Nemo: Yes, and I see why. I've modified the statement so that it's more clear. Thanks!

Comment: I note that in both the examples, the sum of *absolute* values goes 7 7 5 5 3 3 1. Don't know if this is useful though.

Comment: @AakashM It's not too hard to show that the sum of absolute values is non-increasing, as you observed. The problem is that it's not always possible to make it strictly decrease. If you can make this idea work, I'd LOVE to read the solution.

Comment: This really is a remarkable problem.  It implies, for instance, that the sequence [2, -3, 2] somehow encodes both the concept "5" and the sequence [0, 1, 0].  (Because the former is the move count and the latter is the destination, both of which are unique.)  The moves are reversible; I wonder if any insight can be gained by working backwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way to see why the output vector and the number of steps are the same no matter what index you choose at each step is to look at the problem as a bunch of matrix and vector multiplications.

For the case where `x` has 3 components, think of `x` as a 3x1 vector: `x = [x_0 x_1 x_2]'` (where `'` is the transpose operation). Each iteration of the loop will choose to flip one of `x_0,x_1,x_2`, and the operation it performs on `x` is identical to multiplication by one of the following matrices:

```
      -1  0  0               1  1  0                1  0  1
s_0 =  1  1  0       s_1 =   0 -1  0        s_2 =   0  1  1
       1  0  1               0  1  1                0  0 -1
```

where multiplication by `s_0` is the operation performed if the index `i=0`, `s_1` corresponds to `i=1`, and `s_2` corresponds to `i=2`. With this view, you can interpret the algorithm as multiplying the corresponding `s_i` matrix by `x` at each iteration. So in the first example where `x_1` is flipped at the start, the algorithm computes: `s_1*s_2*s_0*s_1*s_2*s_1[4 -1 -2]' = [0 1 0]'`

The fact that the index you choose doesn't affect the final output vector arises from two interesting properties of the `s` matrices. First, `s_i*s_(i-1)*s_i = s_(i-1)*s_i*s(i-1)`, where `i-1` is computed modulo `n`, the number of matrices. This property is the only one needed to see why you get the same result in the examples with 3 elements:

`s_1*s_2*s_0*s_1*s_2*s_1 = s_1*s_2*s_0*(s_1*s_2*s_1) = s_1*s_2*s_0*(s_2*s_1*s_2)`, which corresponds to choosing `x_2` at the start, and lastly:

`s_1*s_2*s_0*s_2*s_1*s_2 = s_1*(s_2*s_0*s_2)*s_1*s_2 = s_1*(s_0*s_2*s_0)*s1*s2`, which corresponds to choosing to flip `x_2` at the start, but then choosing to flip `x_0` in the third iteration.

The second property only applies when `x` has 4 or more elements. It is `s_i*s_k = s_k*s_i` whenever `k <= i-2` where `i-2` is again computed modulo `n`. This property is apparent when you consider the form of matrices when `x` has 4 elements:

```
       -1  0  0  0          1  1  0  0          1  0  0  0          1  0  0  1
s_0 =   1  1  0  0   s_1 =  0 -1  0  0   s_2 =  0  1  1  0   s_3 =  0  1  0  0
        0  0  1  0          0  1  1  0          0  0 -1  0          0  0  1  1
        1  0  0  1          0  0  0  1          0  0  1  1          0  0  0 -1
```

The second property essentially says that you can exchange the order in which non-conflicting flips occur. For example, in a 4 element vector, if you first flipped `x_1` and then flipped `x_3`, this has the same effect as first flipping `x_3` and then flipping `x_1`.

Comment: Nice observation, but still not a proof.  Although your transformation is mathematically valid, it is possible that `s_i*s_(i-1)*s_i` is a legal sequence of moves while `s_(i-1)*s_i*s_(i-1)` is not a legal sequence of moves (because only negative numbers can be flipped).  So you cannot replace one by the other without reference to the vector on which you are operating.

Comment: Actually, if `s_i*s_(i-1)*s_i` is valid, then you are guaranteed that `s_(i-1)*s_i*s_(i-1)` will also be valid. Take `x = [x_0 ... x_(i-1), x_i, ... x_(n-1)]`. If `s_i*s_(i-1)*s_i` is valid, it implies that both `x_i` and `x_(i-1)` are negative, since first flipping the `i`th element and then flipping the `i-1`th element results in `s_(i-1)*s_i*x=[x_0 ... -x(i)-x_(i-1), x_(i-1), ... x_(n-1)]`. If it is legal to flip the `i`th element (as implied by assuming that `s_i*s_(i-1)*s_i` is legal), then the `i`th element, `x_(i-1)`, is negative. So both `x_i` and `x_(i-1)` are negative.

Comment: This is a great way to think of it. It's essentially the same as the Coxeter proof which uses Bruhat order on the affine symmetric group (generated by s0 s1 s2 with si^2 = id and the braid relations si si-1 si = si-1 si si-1). Not to spoil the fun, but the number of moves is how many multiplications are required to get back to the identity (inversion number, coxeter length, many other names). Modulo the details, this is fantastic.

Comment: I still do not see how this implies the number of steps is fixed, nor the final result.  Could someone elaborate?  Where is the restriction "only flip negative numbers" being used here?

Comment: In my world view, it has to do with whether applying si decreases (flipped a negative) or increases (flipped a positive) the length (minimum number of si's applied to the identity to get the vector).

Answer (score 4):

I picture pushing the negative value(s) out in two directions until they dampen. Since addition is commutative, it doesn't matter what order you process the elements.

Comment: Interesting idea... care to elaborate?

Comment: I guess I played in sandboxes a lot when I was young (a long time ago!). Look at hills and valleys in the sand; if you move sand symmetrically to fill each hole (using "conservation of sand") the outcome is the same no matter where you start.

Comment: +1 for the awesome analogy... not sure it's as rigorous as i wanted (you're not filling holes so much as inverting mounds), but a great way to think of it.

Comment: What you have already is an invariant, describing a common property of all states. What Doug is suggesting a *variant* - something that always increases after each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an observation for when N is divisible by 3...  Probably not useful, but I feel like writing it down.

Let `w` (complex) be a primitive cube root of 1; that is, `w^3 = 1` and `1 + w + w^2 = 0`.  For example, `w = cos(2pi/3) + i*sin(2pi/3)`.

Consider the sum `x_0 + x_1*w + x_2*w^2 + x_3 + x_4*w + x_5*w^2 + ...`.  That is, multiply each element of the sequence by consecutive powers of `w` and add them all up.

Something moderately interesting happens to this sum on each step.

Consider three consecutive numbers `[a, -b, c]` from the sequence, with b positive.  Suppose these elements line up with the powers of `w` such that these three numbers contribute `a - b*w + c*w^2` to the sum.

Now perform the step on the middle element.

After the step, these numbers contribute `(a-b) + b*w + (c-b)*w^2` to the sum.

But since `1 + w + w^2 = 0`, `b + b*w + b*w^2 = 0` too.  So we can add this to the previous expression to get `a + 2*b*w + c`.  Which is very similar to what we had before the step.

In other words, the step merely added `3*b*w` to the sum.

If the three consecutive numbers had lined up with powers of `w` to contribute (say) `a*w - b*w^2 + c`, it turns out that the step will add `3*b*w^2`.

In other words, no matter how the powers of `w` line up with the three numbers, the step increases the sum by `3*b`, `3*b*w`, or `3*b*w^2`.

Unfortunately, since `w^2 = -(w+1)`, this does not actually yield a steadily increasing function.  So, as I said, probably not useful.  But it still seems like a reasonable strategy is to seek a "signature" for each position that changes monotonically with each step...

Comment: I like the idea of thinking of the coordinates of the vector as lying on a circle, but I'm not sure where (if anywhere) this idea of primitive pth roots of unity gets you.

Comment: You're right; it's the same as using any three vectors whose sum is 1.  I started by thinking of the sequence as digits of a base-something number, then started playing with ideas for the "something" and stumbled across the cube root of 1.  Doesn't really help solve the problem.